# Loop through every photo in Photos

Tags: macos, applescript

I want to clean up my Photos library and especially move all my iPhone screenshots to a new album, that way I can easily look through them and delete what I want.

Now for this I first wanted to make a smart album in Photos, but it seems that Photos can't filter on the dimensions of an image, so I started up the AppleScript Editor :).

I created the following script, which works on a "Test Album" I created:

```
tell application "Photos"

    set source_album_name to "Test Album"
    set target_album_name to "Screenshots"

    set target_width to 640
    set target_height to 1136

    if not (exists container named target_album_name) then
        make new album named target_album_name
    end if

    set target_album to container target_album_name
    set source_album to container source_album_name

    set imageList to {}

    repeat with photo in media items in source_album

        if width of photo = target_width and height of photo = target_height then
            set the end of imageList to photo
        end if

    end repeat

    add imageList to target_album

end tell
```

This script loops through an Album named `Test Album` and compares the height and width to the dimensions of an iPhone 5S. When they match, it adds the photo to the `Screenshots` library. No problems there.

Now I want to run this script on my entire photo collection, so I changed the line `repeat with photo in media items in source_album` to `repeat with photo in every media item`.

This generates an error once it is past the first item (`Photos got an error: Can’t get item 2 of every media item. Invalid index`).

After that I changed the code to:

```
set all_images to every media item
repeat with photo in all_images
```

but after loading for a while, the script exits with code -10000, probably because of the amount of photos in that library (27.000).

Is there some way to page through a set like this?

**EDIT:** Changing the `set` line to contain a better query has the same effect, resulting in an `AppleEvent handler failed` with error number `-10000`.

`set all_images to every media item whose width = target_width and height = target_height`

Comment: Is it possible that `every media item` might include, say audio tracks, which may not have a height/width?

Comment: Well, it's a property on the media item object, I would guess the value would be 0 or at least just not included in the query. But I will try to figure it out when it crashes.

Comment: The problem is that the `width` and `height` properties are integers and can never be a `missing value`. (Also tried it, and it crashes right at the first record, with an integer to missing value conversion error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The -10000 error is due to a bug in Photos 1.0. I've filed this with Apple as radar 20626449 (on OpenRadar at http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6090497735000064). The error is intermittent, but the more photos there are in the library, the more likely it is to occur on any given scripting command.

There is no totally reliable way around the error, but one thing that seems to help is if the "All Photos" album is selected in Photos before starting your script. Unfortunately the Photos AppleScript suite doesn't have the ability to select an album, so you'll need to do this manually before starting the script.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is indeed a bug. Been trying to work around it and it happens at random at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mind dropping into the shell in Terminal, or if you can make that work with iPhoto, but if that is ok, this may get you started on finding all files in your HOME directory and below, that are `PNG`s and that match your sizes...

```
#!/bin/bash
isIphone() {
   # Get width using sips, don't bother getting height if not 640 wide
   w=$(sips -g pixelWidth  "$1" | awk 'END{print $2}')
   [ "$w" != "640" ] && return
   # Get height using sips, just return if not iPhone size
   h=$(sips -g pixelHeight "$1" | awk 'END{print $2}')
   [ $h != "1136" ] && return
   # Output image size and name
   echo $w,$h, $1
}

# Go through all PNG files in HOME directory listing iPhone-sized ones
find ~ -iname "*.png" -type f -print0 | while read -d $'\0' -r file ; do isIphone "$file"; done
```

**Output**

```
640,1136, ./iPhone/2013 09 iPhone/IMG_0269.PNG
640,1136, ./iPhone/2013 09 iPhone/IMG_0363.PNG
640,1136, ./iPhone/2013 09 iPhone/IMG_0376.PNG
```

Comment: Not so sure this is possible, because the information of the files is stored in the library and does not have to be the same for the file on disk (the file could be iCloud synced or not).

Comment: Ok, no problems. I wasn't sure if it might help - it was just something that might have got you started if no-one comes up with anything better :-)